# mysql xampp cannot turn on suddenly

Tags: mysql, xampp

i have been trying to turn on mysql on xampp but it wouldn't turn on. i went to mysql logs and to the errorlog file and here are the things they gave.

```
2015-11-23 10:54:20 d274 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
151123 10:54:20 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
151123 10:54:20 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
151123 10:54:20 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
151123 10:54:20 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
151123 10:54:20 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
151123 10:54:20 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
151123 10:54:20 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
151123 10:54:20 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
151123 10:54:20 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
151123 10:54:20 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 1735623
151123 10:54:20 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
151123 10:54:20 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
151123 10:54:20 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
151123 10:54:20 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
151123 10:54:20 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 1735633
151123 10:54:20 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
151123 10:54:20 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
151123 10:54:20 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.22-72.0 started; log sequence number 1735633
151123 10:54:20 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
151123 10:54:20 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Answer (score 0):

The log seems ok for me. Maybe you have permission problem, try (right click) run as Administrator the Xampp

Answer (score 0):

try check your active port, maybe used by another program. Mysql use 3306 as default port. go to your xampp folder try find "portcheck.exe" or something like that. see if your mysql port used or free.